# How reliable is the ASP.NET Validator?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, validation, code-behind

I decided to use the **ASP.NET Validator** to validate my dozens of inputs of my **WebForm**. It works fine on the **Client** side. I mean, i'm totally ok with validating the inputs without "Posting the Page back" etc.

But when i try to use the Validator on **code behind**, it gives me that `Page.Isvalid` attribute, and i get confused with its reliability. Here is the questions that i couldn't answer by myself:

1. Is Validator reliable enough to be used on client side? (Besides disabling **javascript**, can it be manipulated?)
2. How does this Validator reach the validity information on **server side**? (Is there a generated C# Validator code somewhere or does it take the info directly from the **client-side**?)

Here is the code that i wrote to validate my inputs also on server side:

```
foreach (IValidator iValidator in Page.Validators)
            {
                if (!iValidator.IsValid) { return false; }
            }
```

But, is it independent from .aspx and .js? Can i rely on it on server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always validate also on serverside, this is mostly done automatically by calling `Page.Validate`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ke7bxeh.aspx):

> This method is invoked when a user clicks any ASP.NET server control
>   that has the **CausesValidation** property set to true, which is the
>   default. These include the Button, ImageButton, and LinkButton Web
>   server controls, the HtmlInputButton, HtmlInputImage, and HtmlButton
>   HTML server controls, and controls that can automatically post back to
>   the server such as the TextBox, CheckBox, ListControl, and
>   BulletedList controls.

If you want to force validation of a different `ValidationGroup` you can call it manually:

```
Page.Validate("MyValidationGroup");
If(Page.IsValid)
{
    // ...
}
```

Note that you should check `Page.IsValid` only after you have called the `Page.Validate` method, or set the `CausesValidation` property to true in the `OnServerClick` event handler for an ASP.NET server control that initiated the form processing.

Comment: Thanks for more information, but how does this Page.IsValid really works?

Comment: @3yanlis1bos: That is just a property which does nothing but return a `bool` which was set from `Page.Validate(validationGroup)`.  This method will call every related validator's `Validate` method, for example a `RequiredFieldValidator` which checks if the according control(`ControlToValidate`) is empty or not.

Comment: Where does this validity information come from? Is it dependent to js or anything changeable on the client-side, or is it really comes from methods that are stored in dlls?

Comment: @3yanlis1bos: I've just edited my comment. Every validator has a `Validate` method(protected and inherited from `BaseValidator)`, you cannot call it yourself) which is called then. So - of course - it is a serverside method and independent of the clientside.

Comment: Allright. Next time i'll be clearer with my question. Thanks for satisfying answer.